# randomize linked list in C

Tags: c, random, linked-list

Suppose I have a reserved space in memory in a C program, for a linked list containing 1000 items. Each item contains nothing but a reference for next item in the list (last points to the first one). But now they are all set to null, it's just reserved space.

Next I have a `rand()` function which gives me a random number from 1 to 1000. My question is, is there any simple way how to randomize this list using this function in following way: When I start at first element, I will traverse the whole list, that is, there wont be circles in the list smaller than the whole list.

Comment: What is the use of your random number here?

Comment: Sound simple enough - what have you tried?

Comment: I should use it to randomize the list. But I dont know how... The naive approach would to iterate through items in sequential order and use this number as index for the "next" element. But there is big chance that two items will point to same item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you have an array of 1000 nodes all zeroed.  For sake of argument, that array is named `node_array`, and the link field is called `next`.  You also have a pointer called `head` that can point to one of the nodes.

You can allocate an array of 1000 integers:

```
enum { NUM_ITEMS = 1000 };
int mapper[NUM_ITEMS];
```

You can initialize the list so each number appears once:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
    mapper[i] = i;
```

You can shuffle the list.  (I should really check in Knuth (The Art of Computer Programming) or Bentley (Programming Pearls or More Programming Pearls), but I think the correct algorithms for random shuffling require a different random number generator — one that generates a random number in the range [n..m) — rather than one that just generates a number in the range 0..999).

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
{
    int j = rand();
    int t = mapper[j];
    mapper[j] = mapper[i];
    mapper[i] = t;
}
```

You can now thread through the array of nodes, linking them in the sequence in the `mapper` array.  Because there were no duplicates in the array, there are no cycles in the list.

```
head = &node_array[mapper[0]];

for (i = 1; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
{
    head->next = head;
    head = &node_array[mapper[i]];
}
```

Et voilà...

Comment: This seems to be what I want to do. Thank you :-)

Comment: Double check 0..999 vs 1..1000 and watch for off-by-one errors.  Untested code!  You've just been warned.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted the idea how to do that. I'll test it, thanks.

Comment: To be pedantic, this doesn't guarantee that there is no cycle. E.g., if #2 is shuffled to node1, #3 to node2 and #1 to node3, then there will be a cycle from node1->node2->node3->node1.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that does not require extra space. Although note that `rand()` is called random number of times for each node assignment:

```
struct Node
{
    Node* next;
};

int main()
{   
    Node nodes[1000];
    Node* pNext = NULL; 
    Node* pHead = NULL; 
    Node* pTail = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    // reset .next to NULL
    memset(nodes, 0, sizeof(nodes));
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    pHead = &nodes[ rand() % (1000)];           
    pTail = pHead;
    // need only 999 runs as one node is already assigned
    for (i = 0; i < 999; ++i)
    {   
        pTail->next = pTail;
        while ((pNext = &nodes[ rand() % (1000)]) && pNext->next);
        pTail->next = pNext;
        pTail = pNext;
    }
    // pTail->next = pHead; // uncomment if you need circular list
}
```